# Where do I find the program to go with the LEGO 51515?

Tags: mindstorms, software, robot-inventor

I got a LEGO Mindstorms 51515, and I have finished building my 1st robot, and now would like to program it. However, I cannot find any companion program to use. Where can I install the companion program? (Also if there is a Linux program that can be used I would like to know).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The "App" page](https://www.lego.com/en-us/themes/mindstorms/app) does seem to be hard to find at the moment. I found it by clicking on this little icon on [the MINDSTORMS "About" page](https://www.lego.com/en-us/themes/mindstorms/about).

[image: screenshot of web page with arrow pointing to link]

The app is distributed through various app stores:

- [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/lego-mindstorms-robot-inventor/9mtq0n7w1d6x?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) (Windows)
- [Apple App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/lego-mindstorms-inventor/id1515448947) (macOS/iOS)
- [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lego.retail.mindstorms&hl=en_US&gl=US) (Android/Cromebook)
- [Amazon App Store](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08LDQ2DKL) (Kindle Fire)

There isn't currently any option for Linux, but there is a 3rd party project call [Pybricks](https://pybricks.com) that is working on supporting the 51515, so keep an eye on that if you use Linux.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this review on Rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com/blog/315/review-51515-mindstorms-robot-inventor/), the same app you download for the building instructions is the one you use to program it. Did you download an app for instructions?